# Springboot exception handler doesn't catch exception

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

In Spring boot and rest application, i have configured a exception handler as following. It works fine if an exception is thrown after request makes it to rest service.

The Rest api expects Content-Type of "application/json" and If I do not send that content-type header to the api, exception handler does not catch the exception. It prints following information in the log:

```
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/app/v1.0/customers/customer/zones/zoneName.]
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /app/v1.0/customers/customer/zones/zoneName.
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request
```

Here's the exception handler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController  
public class ServiceExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)  
    public final ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> handleException(Throwable ex,WebRequest req)
    {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = null;
        if (ex instanceof ApiException)
        {
            errorResponse = new ErrorResponse((ApiException) ex);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.error(ex);
            errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
            errorResponse.setCode(HttpCodes.HTTP_CODE_500);
            errorResponse.setError(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorResponse,
                HttpStatus.valueOf(errorResponse.getCode()));

    }
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)
    {
        Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<String, String>();
        responseBody.put("path", request.getContextPath());
        responseBody.put("message",
                "The URL you have reached is not in service at this time (404).");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(responseBody, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your class will only catch errors raised from within a controller. The error you are seeing occurs before a controller is invoked, as Spring cannot find a controller to handle the request.

```
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /app/v1.0/customers/customer/zones/zoneName.
DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported
```

Notice the handler is null.

You will also need to implement a `HandlerExceptionResolver` to handle that type of exception: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

See [Spring exception handler outside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999949/spring-exception-handler-outside-controller) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Adam. That provided really good pointers to find a working solution but it took me a while to fix it. Looks like spring does not like two exception handlers. I had ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver and ResponseEntityExceptionHandler hence the exceptions were always going to ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. I removed ResponseEntity one and kept just the global ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Here's final solution:

```
@ControllerAdvice  
public class SpringExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver
{
    @ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleControllerException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, WebRequest req)
    {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = null;
        ex.printStackTrace();
        errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setCode(HttpCodes.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        errorResponse.setError(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorResponse,
            HttpStatus.valueOf(errorResponse.getCode()));
    }
}
```

Now I need to make some changes to make it work for all exceptions including controller thrown but that is for later. (Thanks Adam).

Important note: if there's both a global handler and an entity handler, spring ignores global handler.