# Trying to get Spring Boot app to send an error response message when request does not have "Content-type" HTTP request header

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am still really new with Spring Boot, but I have a web application, that is setup to handle either XML requests (when the requests have a "Content-type: application/xml" header, or JSON requests (when the requests have a "Content-type: application/xml" header), and I noticed that if the "Content-type" header is either missing, or contains something other than "Content-type: application/xml" or "Content-type: application/json", I get a "415" response error code.  The logging also shows a message like:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported]
```

I found this older SO thread:

[Springboot exception handler doesn't catch exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191349/springboot-exception-handler-doesnt-catch-exception)

and have been trying to implement the code that was posted by "Sannu" on Dec 17 '16 at 13:55.  This is the code that I built and am testing (as a test, I was trying to change the error response code to "500" and also have a error response message):

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;

import mil.nga.geoaxis.pdp.models.ErrorResponse;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;


@ControllerAdvice  
public class SpringExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver
{
    @ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object>     handleControllerException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, WebRequest req)
{
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = null;
    //ex.printStackTrace();
    errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    errorResponse.setCode(HttpCodes.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()=[" + HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() + "]");
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: ex.getMessage()=[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
    int myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    
    errorResponse.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    errorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

    myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.valueOf(errorResponse.getCode()));
    
}
}
```

However, when I test, and send a request with no "Content-type:" header (using curl), I am still getting what appears to be a response with "100" response code, then a response with a "415" response code, and no response message.

FYI, here is part of the logging that is appearing:

```
In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()=[500]
In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: ex.getMessage()=[Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported]
In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[0]
In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[500]
WARN 15428 --- [io-18443-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler      ....errorhandling.SpringExceptionHandler#handleControllerException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException, WebRequest)
```

Can anyone suggest why this does not seem to be able to send the error code and response message?

[FYI, I am doing this under Spring Boot 2.5.6.]

Thanks in advance!

Jim

EDIT 1:  I modified the class per huy's suggestion to this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;



@ControllerAdvice  
public class SpringExceptionHandler 
{
    @ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleControllerException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, WebRequest req)
{
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = null;
    //ex.printStackTrace();
    errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    //errorResponse.setCode(HttpCodes.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()=[" + HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() + "]");
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: ex.getMessage()=[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
    int myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    
    errorResponse.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    errorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

    myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.valueOf(415))
            .body(ex.getMessage());
    
}
}
```

The code above causes a response with error code 415, and the text error message from the HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException exception.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to extend ExceptionHandlerException..., it's used by default to resolve error. You only need only ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler, ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver will auto scan annotation ExceptionHandler and handle it.

Comment: huy - can you clarify?  Are you saying that if I just make the SpringExceptionHandler class (and it doesn't extend ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver), then the handleControllerException() method would be able to return the ResponseEntity successfully and cause the response that I want?  Jim

Comment: extend ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver is weird and might be cause conflict the resolver sometime... I don't recommend it... By the way, the default resolver of spring will auto detect and handle annotation ExceptionHandler...

Comment: huy - I got it working (kind of) and will update the original post with the new/final code.  Can you change your comment to an answer so that I can select it?  Thanks!

Comment: i added the answer

Comment: Why the complexity with an exception resolver etc. just write a servlet filter, which prevents a request without a `Content-Type` header. You are making it overly complex trying to solve this with an exception handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extend ExceptionHandlerException..., it's used by default to resolve error.

You only need only ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler, ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver will auto scan annotation ExceptionHandler and handle it.