# Followup to earlier Spring Boot Exception Handling question - Best way to co-exist with already existing error handling?

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is a followup question to an earlier question about Spring Boot exception handling:

[Trying to get Spring Boot app to send an error response message when request does not have "Content-type" HTTP request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208722/trying-to-get-spring-boot-app-to-send-an-error-response-message-when-request-doe)

Prior to that earlier thread, we already had a class that extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler (named "myResponseEntityExceptionHandler") which handled a validation exception and also was a catch-all.

But when I was testing the new SpringExceptionHandler (from [Trying to get Spring Boot app to send an error response message when request does not have "Content-type" HTTP request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208722/trying-to-get-spring-boot-app-to-send-an-error-response-message-when-request-doe)), I found that I had to remove the already existing class, in order for the SpringExceptionHandler to work (if I recall, if both were in the build, then the code in the SpringExceptionHandler was never used).

Now that I have the SpringExceptionHandler working I wanted to try to make it so that we could handle both the exceptions that were handled by the already-existing class, and also the exception that was handled by the SpringExceptionHandler.

So I am wondering what approach you all would recommend for doing that?

- Modify the newer SpringExceptionHandler to incorporate handling the validation exception AND also to be a catch-all for exceptions?
- Maybe modify either the already existing class or the SpringExceptionHandler so that they could both co-exist and work?
- Or maybe there is some other way/approach?

FYI, for reference, here is the code for the "myResponseEntityExceptionHandler" class:

```
package xxx....errorhandling;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException;

import xxx.....ErrorResponse;

/**
 * 
 * Error handler
 * 
 * Any exception thrown by Controllers will be captured by this exception handler
 * and after logging a complete stack trace it will send minimal error message with
 * status code to the caller.   
 * 
 *
 */
@ControllerAdvice
public class myResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(myResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);

/**
 *  This method will catch errors on malformed request payloads
 *  TODO: Send more user friendly error messages describing the error.
 */
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(final HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("Error: Unable to process request.", ex);
    String error = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    Throwable innerThrowable = ex.getCause();
    
    if (innerThrowable instanceof MismatchedInputException) {
        MismatchedInputException mismatchEx = (MismatchedInputException) innerThrowable;
        error = "Invalid input message: " + mismatchEx.getOriginalMessage() 
        + " at line: " + mismatchEx.getLocation().getLineNr()
        + " column: " + mismatchEx.getLocation().getColumnNr();
    }
    

    final ErrorResponse apiError = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

/**
 * Catch errors relating to validation of the request message.
 * @param ex
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
@ExceptionHandler({ RequestValidationException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(final RequestValidationException ex,
        final WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("Error: Unable to process request.", ex);
    final String error = "Missing or invalid parameters - " + ex.getMessage();

    final ErrorResponse apiError = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}


}
```

Thanks again!

Jim

EDIT 2:  When I tried to combined the code from the new "SpringExceptionHandler" with the original "myResponseEntityExceptionHandler", to get:

```
package .....errorhandling;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException;

import ......ErrorResponse;

/**
 * 
 * Error handler
 * 
 * Any exception thrown by Controllers will be captured by this exception handler
 * and after logging a complete stack trace it will send minimal error message with
 * status code to the caller.   
 * 
 *
 */
@ControllerAdvice
public class myResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends     ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger =     LogManager.getLogger(myResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);

/**
 *  This method will catch errors on malformed request payloads
 *  TODO: Send more user friendly error messages describing the error.
 */
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(final HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("Error: Unable to process request.", ex);
    String error = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    Throwable innerThrowable = ex.getCause();
    
    if (innerThrowable instanceof MismatchedInputException) {
        MismatchedInputException mismatchEx = (MismatchedInputException) innerThrowable;
        error = "Invalid input message: " + mismatchEx.getOriginalMessage() 
        + " at line: " + mismatchEx.getLocation().getLineNr()
        + " column: " + mismatchEx.getLocation().getColumnNr();
    }
    

    final ErrorResponse apiError = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

/**
 * Catch errors relating to validation of the request message.
 * @param ex
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
@ExceptionHandler({ RequestValidationException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(final RequestValidationException ex,
        final WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("Error: Unable to process request.", ex);
    final String error = "Missing or invalid parameters - " + ex.getMessage();

    final ErrorResponse apiError = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}


/**
 * Catch errors where the request either does not include "Content-type" header or the value of "Content-type" header is not one that handled.
 * @param ex
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
@ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
public ResponseEntity <Object> handleControllerException(final HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, final WebRequest req)
{
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = null;
    //ex.printStackTrace();
    errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    //errorResponse.setCode(HttpCodes.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()=[" + HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() + "]");
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: ex.getMessage()=[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
    int myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    
    errorResponse.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    errorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

    myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    //return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.valueOf(errorResponse.getCode()));
    //return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.valueOf(415))
            .body(ex.getMessage());
    
} // end handleControllerException()



} // end CLASS myResponseEntityExceptionHandler
```

The build is failing with an "Ambiguous" error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity ......errorhandling.PDPResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleControllerException(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
... 85 more
```

From googling and search SO, it seems that the "Ambiguous" means that I am duplicating a class, but from the source above, I don't see any?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Your not duplicating a class you are creating 2 of the same methods to handle an exception. You cannot have 2 methods to handle the same exception.

Comment: M. Deinum - I am still very new to Spring Boot.  Can you tell me which 2 methods are being duplicated?  I have not been able to discern that.

Comment: You have 2 methods handling the `RequestValidationException` now that there are 2 which one should handle it? How should the framework decide between either one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an approach working, with the 2 separate classes.

What I had to do was to add an "@Order...." annotation to the SpringExceptionHandler class, to set that to the "highest precedence".

Here is the working code:

```
package ......errorhandling;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;

import ......models.ErrorResponse;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SpringExceptionHandler // extends    ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver
{
    @ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleControllerException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, WebRequest req)
{
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = null;
    
    errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    errorResponse.setCode(HttpCodes.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()=[" + HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() + "]");
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: ex.getMessage()=[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
    int myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    
      errorResponse.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    errorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

    myCode = errorResponse.getCode();
    System.out.println("In SpringExceptionHandler.handleControllerException: errorResponse.getCode()/String.valueOf(myCode)=[" + String.valueOf(myCode) + "]");

    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.valueOf(415))
            .body(ex.getMessage());
    
}
}
```